# Setting $location and then filtering with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

For the purposes of navigation, I'm trying to have a button that triggers a function.

This function must first:

-Redirect to `#/`

And then:

-Filter an ng-repeat that exists in this view.

This is what I've tried but no luck.

```
<li><a ng-click="shopsingle()">Shop</a></li>
```

And JS:

```
$scope.shopsingle = function(){
  $location.path("/");

  setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.filterExpr = {"shop" : true};
      console.log($scope.filterExpr);
    });
  }, 300);
};
```

It does redirect to the desired path, where a full ng-repeat list appears, but it won't apply the filter, and console also comes empty.

About the views and routing, I'm using the same template for 2 different views, and showing/hidding parts of if while watching the `$routeParams`:

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
      templateUrl : "home.htm",
      controller : "mainCtrl"
  })
  .when('/:name',
      {
          templateUrl:"home.htm",
          controller:"mainCtrl"
      })
  .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
})
```

And the controller watch:

```
$scope.name = $routeParams.name;

$scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.name; }, function(newVal) { 
  if (!newVal){
    $scope.single = false;
  } else{
    $scope.single = true
  };
  $scope.newname = newVal;
  $scope.chosenexhibitor = $filter("filter")($scope.images, {'name':$scope.newname}, true);
}, true);
```

And the view:

```
<!-- MAIN PAGE -->

<div ng-hide="single" id="tiles" masonry='{ "transitionDuration" : "0.15s" , "itemSelector" : ".tile"}'>
  <div masonry-tile ng-repeat="item in images | filter:filterExpr" class="tile col-xs-3 col-md-3">
    <a href="#/{{item.name}}">            
       <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="img/{{item.link}}">
    </a>
  </div>
</div> 

<!-- SINGLE PAGE -->

<div class="row flexing" ng-show="single">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>{{chosenexhibitor[0].name}}</h1>

        <img ng-src="img/{{chosenexhibitor[0].link}}">

        <a class="back" href="#/">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think we need more code to diagnose, ie the `ng-repeat` and some more context on the redirect (it is redirecting to the same page, controller?)

Comment: When a route changes, the router destroys the scope of the old view and creates a new scope. Any calculations done on the old scope will be lost. Pesistent data should be stored in a service.

Comment: Please see edit.